# Incorrect proposal to dealing with nested radicals?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, nested-radicals

Lets try to calculate this set of nested radicals:

$$f(2)=\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\cdots}}$$

So If we call:
$$f(n)=\sqrt{n\sqrt{(n+1)\sqrt{(n+2)\cdots}}}$$

Of course, this is for: $f(2)$ right, so logically here we must solve for $n=2$

So we square both sides:$$(f(n))^2=n\sqrt{(n+1)\sqrt{(n+2)\cdots}}$$

You might notice something tricky about that nested radical on the right.
$$(f(n))^2=nf(n+1)$$
Now we try to plug $(n-1)$ in on both sides for $n$. 
$$(f(n-1))^2=nf(n)$$
And we square! We are trying to create $(f(n))^2$ again so we can substitute back with earlier steps.
$$(f(n-1))^4=n^2(f(n))^2$$
And we divide to create the term that we need. 
$$\frac{(f(n-1))^4}{n^2}=(f(n))^2$$ 
And we replace:
$$\frac{(f(n-1))^4}{n^2}=nf(n+1)$$
Our last step is to divide by $n$ and plug in $1$. We get a rather auspicious answer that I really didn't quite understand. We are trying to create $f(2)$, right?
$$\frac{(f(n-1))^4}{n^3}=f(n+1)$$
So...we just plug in $1$ for $n.$
$$\frac{(f(0))^4}{1^3}=f(2)$$
And solve: 
$$f(2)=0$$
But it is obvious that $f(2)\not=0$
Can someone please where I went wrong in this proof?

Comment: infinite sum ? which sum ?

Comment: oh **** wrote it wrong, sorry

Comment: dont be sorry, your are very better than me  :)

Comment: When you replace $n$ with $n-1$, you can't leave out one occurrence, you get $f(n-1)^2 = (n-1)f(n)$, not $= nf(n)$.

Comment: $f^2(n-1)=(n-1)f(n)$

Comment: i guess it because when you put n-1 you must refine the domain of n to n>=3

Comment: from(n>=2) to (n>=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have reccurence
$$
(f(n))^2=nf(n+1)
$$
then you will have
$$
(f(n-1))^2=(n-1)f(n)
$$
instead of
$$
(f(n-1))^2=nf(n).
$$

Comment: or refine the domain ?